# How to setup a 3 levels of branches in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I'm somewhat new to Git.  So I've got the origin/master and origin/upbranch on my remote server.  I've also got a master branch on my local machine.  How do I go about setting it up so that I can push to origin/upbranch from my local machine?  Also, how would I set up pulling into origin/master from origin/upbranch?  I can access the remote server via static address, but have no address to access local from remote.

Also, any references you would recommend for someone learning Git?

**Edit:** renamed origin/upstream to origin/upbranch, since I may have misunderstood its meaning.

master (local) -> origin/upbranch (remote) -> origin/master (remote)

Comment: For tutorials, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183918/any-good-git-tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is upstream a branch in this scenario? It sure looks like it. I believe that branch name is really going to confuse people.

But to answer some of the questions:

Assuming you have `master -> origin/master` and `upstream -> origin/upstream`. It looks like you already have your local branches tracking the remote ones.

> **How do I go about setting it up so that I can push to origin/upstream
>   from my local machine?**

*Switch to the upstream branch*

```
 > git checkout upstream 
 ... awesome changes 
 > git commit -a -m "Did something awesome." 
 > git push origin upstream
```

You use checkout to switch to your locally tracked upstream branch. Make some changes. Commit them, them push them back to origin.

> **Also, how would I set up pulling into origin/master from
>   origin/upstream?**

You don't directly do this. You have to merge locally then push.

```
> git checkout upstream
> git pull origin upstream
> git checkout master
> git merge --no-ff upstream
> git commit -a -m "Merged upstream into master."
> git push origin master
```

Change the local branch to upstream. Pull any changes from the remote branch. If there were merge problems you'll have to fix + commit first before switch back to master. Switch to the master branch and merge in the changes from upstream into master. I turn off fast-forwarding so that it creates a new merge commit instead of just moving the pointer of master.

Commit the merge and then push it back to the remote server.

*Confusion*

If upstream is supposed to be another remote location like origin then I don't know exactly what you are trying to do since you listed upstream as origin/upstream.

From what I have seen the name upstream would be used to name another remote location. In that case, origin would be similar to upstream. Not master to upstream. But I kept with the assumption you created 2 branches, one called master (created by default) and one called upstream and you'd like to work in them and merge upstream into master.

Comment: Yes, I meant two different branches on the remote: origin/master and origin/upbranch.  upbranch would obtain all the pushes from the local.  master would obtain all the pulls from upbranch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new branch, track it and it would be automatically set up.

```
git branch --track branch1 origin/branch1
```

If you want to change tracking for an existing branch, you need to modify you .git/config file

Example

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git://github.com/canuckistani/dotjs-addon.git
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

If you are not comfortable editing the config file you can try as suggested in comment below i.e.

```
git branch --set-upstream branch_name your_new_remote/branch_name
```

Similarly you can setup other remotes like upstream etc.

Comment: "If you want to change tracking for an existing branch, you need to modify you .git/config file."

Not true. If branch1 already exists you can use `git branch --set-upstream branch1 origin/branch1` to set up tracking.

Comment: @vergenzt I added your suggestion in answer as well, but editing the config would work as well. Thanks.